# How to verify an algebraic structure is a ring

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inverse, finite-rings, associativity

I have a problem which ask me to verify that to structures are rings. However,  I'm unsure of how exactly to check each property.  I believe that the first is closed but not sure how to check the additive identity,  Inverse,  associtivity on ⊗ and distribution of ⊗ over ⊕.  For the second one I have no clue because I think it is not closed.  Pleased offer some assistance.

(1) $S=Z$; for all $a, b∈S$,$ a⊕b=a+b+1$ and $a⊗b=ab$

(2) $S ={k/2|k∈Z}$={$...,−5/2,−2,−3/2,−1,−1/2,0,1/2,1,3/2,2,5/2$}; for all $a,b∈S, a⊕b= a+b$ and $a⊗b=2ab$.

Comment: What are the operations on the second case?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is not a ring since
$$a \otimes (b \oplus c) = a(b+c+1)=ab+ac+a$$
while
$$(a \otimes b) \oplus (a \otimes c) = ab+ac+1$$
so equality does not hold for $a \neq 1$.

(2) is a ring because $(S, \oplus)=(\mathbb{Z}/2, +)$ is an abelian group, $\otimes$ is clearly associative since
$$a \otimes (b \otimes c) = 2a(2bc) = 4abc = 2(2ab)c = (a \otimes b) \otimes c$$
and distributivity holds since
$$a \otimes (b \oplus c) = 2a(b+c)=2ab+2ac=(a \otimes b) \oplus (a \otimes c)$$

Comment: Thank you but how would you go about finding the additive identity for the first. Is it 0?  And for the second?

Comment: For the first, you have to find an element $e$ such that $a \oplus e = a$. But now simply solve $a+e+1 = a$ to get $e = -1$. For the second, simply the identity is $0$.